# Unable to display data in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I have created a Label control and gridview. Label shows the data but In Gridview data from database does not populate.
Following is my code. No error is received while doing this

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;



namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select BATSMAN_NAME from RUNS_STATS", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("BATSMAN_NAME"));
        }

        GridView2.DataSource = dr;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure your `Select BATSMAN_NAME from RUNS_STATS` command returns any data? Did you debug your code and check `dr`?

Comment: Because `dr` is an object and not a data container, use `DataTable` instead and fill it with your datareader object.

Comment: 1. Check the SQL statement ..whether it return something.           2. YOu can use dr[index] to fetch the data.                                                                 i.e string col1Value = rdr[0].ToString(); OR string col1Value = rdr["ColumnOneName"].ToString();

Comment: @Soner, Pranav: Yes I am sure. I have debug this code. Select Query is perfect.It Returns values. Dr has it. Thats why I was able to show it on label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SqlDataAdapter & dataset to fill gridview

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select BATSMAN_NAME from RUNS_STATS", con);
    SqlDataAdapter daGrid = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daGrid.Fill(ds);
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: This Worked. Thanks a lot.

            SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnected architecture. Incase the following code doesn't work, check if the Query is appropriate.

```
SqlConnection conobj=new SqlConnection;
SqlCommand cmdobj=new SqlCommand(""Select BATSMAN_NAME from RUNS_STATS", conobj);
SQlDataAdapter sdaobj=new SqlDataAdapter(cmdobj);
DataTable dtobj=new DataTable();
sdaobj.Fill(dtobj);
GridView2.DataSource=dtobj;
GridView2.DataBind();
```